# How to convert decimal number to cents in angular or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, currency-formatting

How to convert `$2.50` in cents using angular / JavaScript. For example output should be `250`.

Comment: Multiply the base value by 100?

Comment: Yup correct. Is there any build-in function for this?

Comment: So at least he needs something like Math.round(100*2.30), then considering there was already a dollar sign in his value, it means he has to parse it from string to float.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about something like this?

```
var currencyValue = (2.50*100).toFixed(1);
```

JavaScript toFixed() method in this case is keeping only one decimal after the multiplication

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatDollarsToCents = function(value) {
    value = (value + '').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
    if (value && value.includes('.')) {
        value = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('.') + 3);
    }
    return value ? Math.round(parseFloat(value) * 100) : 0;
}
```

Comment: can you share some description with the code? code only answers are considered low quality

Comment: sure.. Thanks for the review

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow this link:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dollars-to-cents

**Example:**

```
var dollarsToCents = require('dollars-to-cents')

console.log(dollarsToCents('$1,030.25')) // 103025
```